# Why didn't my unanswered question trigger Silencium hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2018

I was just reading the list of hats in Winterbash when I noticed this hat:

[Silencium](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/silencium)

> ask a question that gets no answers within a week of being posted

Then it occurred to me that one of my question falls in the same category.

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779721/notificationlistenerservice-is-not-working-for-hangouts) question on main site on Dec 14. It hasn't got any answer yet.

And I haven't got that hat yet. So how come it didn't trigger the hat? It would be good if someone explains me if there is anything else to be taken into account.

Comment: [Identical question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320785/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Glad to see you now have this hat!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some hats require the qualifying posts to have a positive score. This is the case for Silencium as well. Your question is (while I'm writing this) still at 0  score ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53779721/timeline)) and does not qualify (yet).

> #### Implicit quality requirements
>
> To prevent people from posting nonsense just to earn a hat, most hats that require creating content, especially questions and answers, have some requirements that may not be mentioned in the hat description. Generally this involves questions/answers having a positive score (i.e. getting at least one upvote)

(mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232))